# Get a partition name with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, drive, removable-storage

I have a flash drive which I formatted so that the volume label on the drive is "PHILIP".

[image]

I am using `Get-PSDrive H -PSProvider FileSystem` to determine if the drive is plugged in, however I would really like to determine if the drive is plugged in by the volume label, i.e. `Get-PSDrive -VolumeLabel PHILIP -PSProvider FileSystem`. Of course the `VolumeLabel` parameter does not exist so this doesn't work.

Is there a way to list the drives in a computer by volume name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use WMI, I guess:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_Volume | ? { $_.Label -eq 'PHILIP' }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [DriveInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx) class from the .NET framework as well:

```
PS> [System.IO.DriveInfo]::GetDrives()
Name               : C:\
DriveType          : Fixed
DriveFormat        : NTFS
IsReady            : True
AvailableFreeSpace : 217269202944
TotalFreeSpace     : 217269202944
TotalSize          : 320070479872
RootDirectory      : C:\
VolumeLabel        : OS
```

You can then pipe that to the `Where-Object` cmdlet (both `?` and `Where` are aliases) to filter that to just the volume you are looking for:

```
PS> [System.IO.DriveInfo]::GetDrives() | ? {$_.VolumeLabel -eq "PHILIP" }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Get-WMIObject like Joey proposes.
To link the wmi results to for example a get-partition i use the caption parameter.
In this example I set the partition letter of volume Philip to D

> $datavolume=Get-WMIObject Win32_Volume | ? { $_.Label -eq 'PHILIP' }
>
> $datavolume=$datavolume.Caption
>
> get-partition -DiskNumber 0 | where {$_.accesspaths -like "*$datavolume*"} | Set-Partition -NewDriveLetter D